# iphone: managing timers on different views

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Actually I want to stop the timer of one view when I go on next view, so what can i do?
That means when I open one view the timer is start , when I come to next view the timer is still running. Plz help me for that.

Comment: Please Change the title to reflect the Question.

Answer (score 1):

```
[timer invalidate]
```

Comment: I have used this method

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(10)
         target : self
           selector:@selector(onTimer)
          userInfo : nil
           repeats : YES];

Comment: That method returns the NSTimer. Store the timer in an ivar and invalidate it in -viewWillDisappear. You should also invalidate this timer whenever you set the timer (so in your setTimer: accessor), and you should invalidate before releasing the ivar in -dealloc.